# Marking word as "find and replace" in Microsoft Word with RegEx

Tags: regex, vba, ms-word

I try to highlight a word found by RegEx, and if the right to replace it with its corresponding substitute.

The code works correctly only if NOT substituted.

Probably should every time rearrange???

```
Sub Replace()
Dim regExp As Object
Set regExp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
Dim arr As Variant
Dim arrzam As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim choice As Integer
Dim Document As Word.Range
Set Document = ActiveDocument.Content

On Error Resume Next
'EGN
'IBAN

arr = VBA.Array("((EGN(:{0,1})){0,1})[0-9]{10}", _
"[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}[0-9]{7}([a-zA-Z0-9]?){0,16}")
arrzam = VBA.Array("[****]", _
"[IBAN]")
With regExp
    For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
        .Pattern = arr(i)
        .Global = True
        For Each Match In regExp.Execute(Document)            
            ActiveDocument.Range(Match.FirstIndex, Match.FirstIndex +     Match.Length).Duplicate.Select
            choice = MsgBox("Replace " & Chr(34) & Match.Value & Chr(34) & " with " & Chr(34) & arrzam(i) & Chr(34) & "?", _
                vbYesNoCancel + vbDefaultButton1, "Replace")
        If choice = vbYes Then          
          Document = .Replace(Document, arrzam(i))
        ElseIf choice = vbCancel Then          
          Next
        End If
        Next
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there are several things wrong with this.

First, the each Match in Each Match is static, determined at the moment of the first loop. You're changing the document in the meantime, so each successive Match looks at an old position.

Second, you're replacing all the occurrences at one time, so there is no need to loop through them. It seems a one line, one time Replace could do the same thing.

Comment: "so each successive Match looks at an old position" - Yes it is. That  why I was thinking that needs  to be rearenge every time. But not shure about it

Comment: "so each successive Match looks at an old position" - Yes it is. That  why I was thinking that needs  to be rearenge every time. But not shure about it. "you're replacing all the occurrences at one time" - It is not the idea. I would like to check  word before replace it. Like Find and replace do on a regular document. It It is no problem to recode the all. If you have idea I'll take it.

Comment: The idea of this code is: "find text in document by regex patterns, that are ten of them, and change found words one by one  with ask Yes, No, Cancel. Yes - replace  depending of pattern with relevant to it. No - Go to next found word. Cancel - Exit search.  "